# Conditional events what goes first and after and disable the rest of them on a given condition in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following button:

```
<button type="button" 
        id="btn1" 
        class="btn btn-default disabled" 
        data-id="btn1">
        Click me
</button>
```

And I have this jQuery code:

```
$(function() {
  $("#btn1").click(function() {
    alert('Clicked');
  });

  $('button.btn.btn-default.disabled').click(function(ev) {
    var id = $(this).attr('data-id');

    if (id == 'btn1') {
      alert('You click me once');
    }
  });
});
```

If you click the `#btn1` you will get into the first alert and then you will go into the second one. Example [here](https://jsfiddle.net/reynierpm/6s4zmyfg/1/).

I need to execute first this event `$('button.btn.btn-default.disabled').click()` and then if the `id` match disable/undbind the rest of the events associated to the button with the matched ID.

Any help?

Comment: Couldn't you do this check to disable/unbind other events from certain nodes at the time you bind rather than on click?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Multiple jQuery event handlers (and DOM2 event handlers) on the same element for the same event are triggered in the order in which they were attached. There's no mechanism for jumping the queue. So you'll need to register your second handler first.

Once you've done that, you can use `ev.stopImmediatePropagation()` to prevent other handlers for the same event on that element from being triggered. And/or remove other handlers via `off`, etc.

Example:

```js
$(function() {
  $('button.btn.btn-default.disabled').click(function(ev) {
    var id = $(this).attr('data-id');

    if (id == 'btn1') {
      console.log('You click me once');
      ev.stopImmediatePropagation();
    }
  });
  $("#btn1").click(function() {
    console.log('Clicked btn1');
  });
  $("#btn2").click(function() {
    console.log('Clicked btn2');
  });
});
```

```html
<button type="button" 
        id="btn1" 
        class="btn btn-default disabled" 
        data-id="btn1">
        btn1
</button>
<button type="button" 
        id="btn2" 
        class="btn btn-default disabled" 
        data-id="btn2">
        btn2
</button>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 1):

This should do what you need:

```
$(function() {
  var $disabledButtons = $('button.btn.btn-default.disabled');
  function handleBtn1() { /* Do whatever `btn1` needs */ }
  function handleButtonClick(e) {
    var id = $(this).prop('id');

    if (id == 'btn1') {
      handleBtn1();
      $disabledButtons.off('click', handleButtonClick);
    }
  }
  $disabledButtons.on('click', handleButtonClick);
});
```